# continue button doesn't work in checkout page

Tags: checkout

My Website :http://www.hbherb.com/ and I can't able to move into the next step in the checkout, I have tried all the solution, none of them work, please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Since when it is happening? did you make some changes and it started in your site?

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: The issue appeared after recent changes? or due to some upgrade?

Comment: recently this issue happened, and I have checked in firebug and error says :

Comment: (index):6 Error parsing a meta element's content: ';' is not a valid key-value pair separator. Please use ',' instead.

Comment: do you have any idea about this error?

Answer (score 2):

Check this screenshot. 
Your saveBilling action is producing 500 Internal server error. Please check it out. ideally You must be having error messages in your

**magento/var/log/system.log**

To enable error logging you must go to, 
System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> developer -> Enable logging settings.

Cheers.... ! Hope this helps...

[image: Screenshot of internal server error.]